# Python Script to run a basic scan throws print error

Tags: python, nmap

I am familiar with python although it's been years since I've used it since I have taken more senior roles where my scripting skills have diminished from non-use. I have received the following error and supplied the code in use below. Grateful for any insight shared.

## ./portscan1.py

File "/home/kali/pythonprograms/scanning/./portscan1.py", line 12
print "Port %d is closed" % (port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

```
                                
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "10.10.1.23"
port = 443

def portscanner(port):
        if sock.connect_ex((host,port)):
                print "Port %d is closed" % (port)
        else:
                print "Port %d is opened" % (port)

portscanner(port)
```

I attempted to add parenthesis () as the error output suggested with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

You must add parenthesis like this (for python 3):

```py
print("Port %d is opened" % (port))
```

Or you can try this:

```py
print("Port {} is opened".format(port))
```

Or you can also try f string:

```py
print(f"Port {port} is opened")
```